# Redirect to page only once?

Tags: php, sql, redirect

I have this piece of php code that looks up the account prompt function on my website. basically if a user has violated a term and condition on the site, at login they are redirected to a prompt page that says you are very naughty and here's a warning.

My code is this:

```
 <?php

$account_prompt = account_prompt();
while ($prompt = mysql_fetch_array($account_prompt)) 


 if ($prompt['account_prompt'] == '1')  {
    redirect_to("prompt.php"); 
 }
 ?>
```

My question is how can i get it to only redirect once? 
Thanks

Comment: On the prompt.php page update the database so that `'account_prompt'` field is set back to 0. Then next time they log in they will not be prompted.

Comment: erm yea but i was going to do it when they click an i agree statement. but if its not possible to redirect once then perhaps if its easier to just set the value back to 0 then yes that will be better

Comment: Don't you want to redirect them everytime they login until they click the I Agree button? Either you want to show it to them once and only once, or you want to show it every time until they click I agree. If you want both then you need to track the data in two different fields in the database (maybe account_prompt and account_prompt_accepted). If you want it to show only once then when the page loads set the field back to 0

Comment: I'm still confused. You want to redirect once based on a value stored in the database, but you don't want to change the database to say that the redirect has happened until after the user has clicked something on "prompt.php" page. I don't see how you can have both. Either keep showing the prompt page until they click "I agree" or reset the database value when you show the page, or have another column saying that you showed it but they didn't agree

Answer (score 1):

He just redirects 1ce unless you are stucked in an endless loop...

Try this

```
if (isset($prompt['account_prompt']) && $prompt['account_prompt'] == '1')  {
    header("Location: prompt.php"); 
    exit;
}
```

Comment: And `exit;` would be nice there

Comment: thanks tried the original code you gave, didn't work. whats that exit; you said in your comment after, should i add a second exit; ?

Comment: Wait wait, what exactly are you doing here, I guess you've not shared your entire code I guess, `exit;` is used to exit the script, so it doesn't go ahead..kinda **STOP** so is your agree statement and this script on the same page?

Comment: when the user logs in they go to dashboard.php as normal. otherwise if they are to be prompted and the account_prompt is set to = 1 then the dashboard.php has that code in it to redirect them to prompt.php. thats all. but after they've accepted the statement i want them to be able to go to their dashboard but because of the redirec they just go back to prompt.php

Comment: @DaveSmith I am sure you are stucked in an endless loop, because redirect only happens 1s...

Answer (score 0):

Use a flag which is set to 1 according to your condition, and take the redirect out of the loop.

```
           $flag = 0;
           while ($prompt = mysql_fetch_array($account_prompt))  {


                if ($prompt['account_prompt'] == '1') $flag = 1;
            }

            if ($flag == 1)
                  redirect_to("prompt.php");
```

Comment: Do you have the same code to check account_prompt in the prompt.php too?